# Using jsPlumb with leaflet to connect markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, jsplumb

I have a leaflet map with lots of markers on it. I need to connect the markers to each other. Can I use jsPlumb for this? Is it feasible. Or should I just connect them by a geoJSON line in leaflet?

> I want jsPlumb for this because I need to show directional arrows on the connections.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution my self. The best way to go around this is to use the Polyline Decorator plugin for leaflet. You can get it [here](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator)

> This library supports directional arrows for polylines.